# How do i use setState to update an object inside an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

This is the structure of my state object

```
this.state = {
    navTabs: [
       {
         name: "Overview",
         isActive: true,
         clickHandler: (ev) => {
           this.setState(...);
         }
       },
       {
         name: "Projects",
         isActive: false,
         clickHandler: (ev) => {
           this.setState(...);
         }
       }
    ]
}
```

I would like to change the `isActive` value of each object when the user clicks a navigation tab. Please how can I do this?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-e5ecvx

Answer (score 0):

In your `onClick` handler on the `navTab` html element, you'll want to call `this.setState({ isActive: <value here> })`

Comment: Thank you, I also tried this at first but each `navTab` has to have it's own `isActive` value for toggling.

Answer (score 0):

1. Keep you data clean first, Write a single handler function:

   ```
   navTabs: [
       {
        name: "Overview",
        isActive: true
      },
      {
        name: "Projects",
        isActive: false
      }
   ]
   ```
2. Depending on the requirement write your **clickHandler**. I am doing toggling in below code

   ```
   clickHandler = ()=>{
      const updatedState ==this.state.navTabs.map(navTab=>({...navTab,isActive:!navTab.isActive}))
       this.setState({
         navTabs:updatedState
       })
   }
   ```
3. Give it a try your **isActive** will get toggler, but then ultimately it depends on your requirement. If you are passing your **navTabs** as **props** to a child component and clicking on a particular navTab, then logic and code will be different.

Comment: I would try this out, but your clickHandler would set all the isActive in the navTabs array to false. That's the problem I'm facing...

Comment: @Tmcool: Indeed it modify them all, but not to false, it will reverse them. You haven't mentioned what you are trying to achieve, That's why I wrote a general solution friend :) If you can let me know the scenario, I may help you more :) But today I have so much task at hand. Tomorrow I will see your problem hopefully. Do Remind me:) Thanks Enjoy coding